# Каково назначение переменной одно подчеркивание «_»?

Tags: python, переменные

Что означает `_` после `for` в этом коде?

```
if tbh.bag:
   n = 0
   for _ in tbh.bag.atom_set():
      n += 1
```

<sub>перевод вопроса [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/14227417) от участника [@alwbtc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718762/alwbtc)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/14227417

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`_` имеет 5 основных стандартных применений в Python:

1. Для хранения результата последнего выполненного выражения в сеансе интерактивного интерпретатора. Этот прецедент был создан стандартным интерпретатором CPython, и другие интерпретаторы последовали его примеру.
2. В качестве универсального имени переменной, указывающей на то, что часть результата функции намеренно игнорируется (концептуально, она отбрасывается.). Как в коде типа:

   ```
   label, has_label, _ = text.partition(':')
   ```
3. Как часть определения функции (используя либо `def` или `lambda`), где сигнатура фиксируется (например, обратным вызовом или родительским классом API), но эта конкретная реализация функции не нуждается во всех параметры, как в коде, например:

   ```
   callback = lambda _: True
   ```
4. Линтер python распознает подчеркивание как преднамеренно неиспользуемую переменную (оба варианта использования указаны выше). Например

   ```
   year, month, day = date()
   ```

   вызовет предупреждение о ворсе, если переменная `day` не будет использоваться позже в коде, если `day` действительно не нужен, то исправить можно так:

   ```
   year, month, _ = date()
   ```

   То же самое с лямбда-функциями

   ```
   lambda arg: 1.0
   ```

   создает функцию, требующую один аргумент, но не использующую его, которая будет перехвачена lint, это можно исправить написав

   ```
   lambda _: 1.0
   ```

   Неиспользуемая переменная часто скрывает ошибку/опечатку (создан `day`, но в следующей строке используется `dya`)
5. Для поиска перевода в [i18n](https://ru-wikipedia-org.turbopages.org/ru.wikipedia.org/s/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F?turbo_uid=AABrJ2os3WRjEzilc2-WpjGPEgyBE-dY9omsLqNQtQmu0uNoUZcPG4FNagzyP-SHzXPQLnfT5rt3GABH-vnPISPgibn4H6D4Py1o65SwGvpYm1WP&turbo_ic=AABkPK5gUSuZaLo6AfdNHUwcV4-68mh1xhrXCDxXhku13r1pm_j-0qxotHryVjDSMVEGzRyWOmOEdSoY9DGFSdTRYxBXFAXocrkwqKNmM4yGfg3n&parent-reqid=1605946808579838-332573205025166342600332-production-app-host-sas-web-yp-33&trbsrc=wb) (см. например документацию [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#localizing-your-module)), как в подобном коде

   ```
   raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please enter a correct username"))
   ```

   Использование подчеркивания для переводе взято из примеров документации, которые копировались/вставлялись десятилетиями, например:

   ```
   import gettext 
   gettext.bindtextdomain('myapplication', '/path/to/my/language/directory')
   gettext.textdomain('myapplication')
   _ = gettext.gettext
   # ...
   print(_('Это переводимая строка.'))
   ```

<sub>перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/14227417) от участника [@ncoghlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597742/ncoghlan)</sub>

Comment: "предупреждение о ворсе" - звучит красиво ))