# Оптимизация соединений сигналов со слотами

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, lambda

Есть несколько однообразных `Qt` элементов. Допустим, необходимо сделать так, чтобы при вводе слов в `QLineEdit` буквы становились заглавными:

```
self.lineedit1.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.upper(self.lineedit1.text()))
self.lineedit2.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.upper(self.lineedit2.text()))
self.lineedit3.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.upper(self.lineedit3.text()))
```

Т.к. объектов и их сигналов много, а писать повторяющийся код не хочется, решил добавить имена объектов в список и в цикле соединять сигналы:

```
temp = [self.lineedit1, self.lineedit2, self.lineedit3]
for _ in temp:
    _.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.upper(_))
```

Такой подход не всегда корректно работает. В данном примере - изменяет буквы на заглавные только в `self.lineedit3`, т.к. итерация заканчивается на нём.

Есть ли способ избавиться от простыни однообразного кода, ибо объектов >100 с 2-3 сигналами на каждом?

Comment: `_` лучше использовать когда явно хотите указать, что переменной не будете пользоваться. Например как тут: `a, _, c = 1, 2, 3`

Comment: @gil9red т.е. `_` имеет смысл, когда надо "откинуть" часть каких-то передаваемых значений?

Comment: Я бы уточнил что именно, когда значения не важны. Значения будут в переменной `_`, но IDE и всякие синтаксические анализаторы не будут ругаться, что для них в другом случае выделена переменная, что не используется, если бы было без `_`, например для `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3`, когда `b` не используется, но объявлена

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207226/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это особенность лямбд в циклах – если передавать переменную прямо в лямбду, то значение будет только для последней итерации, а чтобы было правильно, нужно в параметр лямбды передавать

Попробуйте так:

```
temp = [self.lineedit1, self.lineedit2, self.lineedit3]
for x in temp:
    x.textChanged.connect(lambda x=x: self.upper(x.text()))
```

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, точно, спасибо