# Особенность работы lambda в цикле

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, lambda, сигналы-слоты

У меня было три `QLineEdit` и функция `upper()`, написанная вне класса. Функция должна переводить вводимый текст в верхний регистр.

Задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213990/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8) связанный с особенностями работы `lambda` в цикле. 
Получил ответ - для того, чтобы `lambda` работала не только для последней итерации, надо в неё передать необязательный аргумент:

```
i.textChanged.connect(lambda i=i: upper(i.text()))
```

И действительно, `lambda`  стала работать и для других итераций, но возникла ошибка:

Код:

```
self.lineedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
self.lineedit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
self.lineedit3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

temp = [self.lineedit1, self.lineedit2, self.lineedit3]
for i in temp:
    i.textChanged.connect(lambda i=i: upper(i.text()))
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

По какой-то причине `i` в `lambda` - строка, а не объект `QLineEdit`.

Решил явно указать объект и текст:

```
for i in temp:
    i.textChanged.connect(lambda obj=i, text=i.text(): upper(obj, text))

def upper(object, text): 
    object.setText(text.upper())
```

Возникла ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

Почему-то `object` всё равно оставался `str` хотя я явно указал, что он `QLineEdit`.

Решил поменять `obj` и `text` местами в `lambda` и `upper()`:

```
for i in temp:
    i.textChanged.connect(lambda text=i.text(), obj=i: upper(text, obj))

def upper(text, object):
    object.setText(text.upper())
```

Всё работает как надо, но остались вопросы:

1. Почему `lambda` первым аргументом принимает вводимый текст, независимо от того, что записано в её аргументах?
2. Если `i` - `str`, то почему работает сточка `text=i.text()` ведь `str` не имеет атрибута `.text()`?

Запись `lambda text=i, obj=i: upper(text, obj)` работает.

Добавил в `upper()` строчки:

```
print(type(text)) -> <class 'str'>
print(type(object)) -> <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit'>
```

3. Как так получается, что `i` - это и `str`, и `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрим https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#signals

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> void QLineEdit::`textChanged`(const QString &text)  [signal]
>
> Этот сигнал испускается всякий раз, когда текст изменяется. `text` - это новый текст.
>
> В отличие от `textEdited()`, этот сигнал также излучается при программном изменении текста, например, путем вызова `setText()`.
>
> Примечание: сигнал уведомителя для `property text`.
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop

Т.е. сигнал `textChanged` и предназначен для того, чтобы в случае изменения
текста в `QLineEdit` уведомить вас об этом и передать
этот новый текст первым параметром. В слоте надо принять это новое значение.

```
def upper(new_text):
    print(f'Это новый текст: {new_text}')
```

В вашем случае вы хотите дополнительно передать некий объект,
который в слоте будет приниматься Вторым аргументом.

```
    temp = [self.lineedit1, self.lineedit2, self.lineedit3]
    for i in temp:
        i.textChanged.connect(lambda text, obj=i: self._upper(text, obj))

def _upper(self, text, object): 
    object.setText(text.upper())
```

> Почему `lambda` первым аргументом принимает вводимый текст, независимо от того,
> что записано в её аргументах?

Потому что так решили разработчики, создавая данный сигнал:

```
void QLineEdit::`textChanged`(const QString &text)  [signal]
```

> Если i - str, то почему работает сточка text=i.text() ведь str не имеет атрибута .text()?

```
# `i` - это не `str`, а один из объектов, находящихся в списке `temp`:

temp = [self.lineedit1, self.lineedit2, self.lineedit3]
for i in temp:
    ...
```

Не надо писать так `lambda text=i, obj=i: upper(text, obj)`
это приведет к некоему непониманию, у читающих ваш код.

> Как так получается, что i - это и str, и QLineEdit?

Пишите так и это будет понятно всем:

```
lambda text, obj=self.line_edit : self.on_text_changed(text, obj)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
# 1        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)
        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(                                    # 2
            lambda text, obj=self.line_edit : self.on_text_changed(text, obj)
        ) 
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

# 1    def on_text_changed(self, new_text):
    def on_text_changed(self, new_text, obj):                                  # 2
        print(f'Это новый текст: {new_text}')
        print(f'Это некий объект: {obj}')                                      # 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Отличный ответ :)