# Вывод на экран значения из словаря , ключ которого был введен пользователем

Tags: python, словари

Мне нужно создать примитивную программу - переводчик, которая выводила бы значение  по введенному пользователем ключу, который соответствует этому значению в словаре. Очень желательно, если код будет действовать по отношению к каждому значению и ключу словаря.

Пример :

```
dict_1 = {'a': 'B','c': 'C'}
```

Базовое условие:
Если пользователь вводит 'a', то программа выдает ему 'B', если пользователь запрашивает 'с', то программа выдает ему 'С'.

Дополнительный вопрос:
Можно ли сделать так , чтобы при вводе 'a' и 'c' одновременно выдавались значения 'B' и 'C' в формате строки?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
my_dict = {'a': 'B', 'c': 'D', 'e': 'F', 'g': 'H'}
```

> чтобы при вводе 'a' и 'c' одновременно выдавались
> значения 'B' и 'C' в формате строки

если под "одновременным вводом а и с" вы имеете ввод слов, а под "выдавались значения В и С" - перевод этого слова в соответствии со значениями словаря как новое слово, то:

- запросите строку у пользователя;
- пройдитесь по ней циклом;
- для каждой буквы найдите соответствие в своем словаре;
- соедините все значения в новое слово:

```
message = input()               # запрос на ввод
new_message = ''                # новая строка

for char in message:            # цикл перебора введенного слова
    guess = my_dict.get(char)   # попытка найти соответствие
    if guess:                   # если найдено:
        new_message += guess    # добавить к новой строке

print(new_message)              # вывод результата (ваш КО ;) )
```

вариант в одну строку:

```
print(''.join(my_dict.get(char, '') for char in input()))
```

результат:

```
>? ac xyz eg 
'BDFH'
```

Comment: в данном случае не стоит называть переменную `_`

Comment: @Danis почему нет? ps не спорю, просто не знаю почему

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1207227/400096, в основном _ используется как переменная которую не будет использовать

Comment: @Danis я посчитал этот print как раз таким случаем )) но - ок, имя всегда информативнее

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_1 = {'a':'B','c':'C'}

key = input() #  c
print(dict_1.get(key))
#  C
```

Если нужно несколько значений - нужно несколько инпутов.