# Я, кажется, нашел синтаксическую ошибку аргументов функции в Python. Что мне делать?

Tags: python, syntax

Я хотел создать функцию в классе, которая принимает 2 аргумента, но вывод от них не зависит:

```
def __eq__ (_, _):
    return True
```

Питон кинул синтаксическую ошибку:

```
File "file.py", line 8
def __eq__ (_, _):
^
SyntaxError: duplicate argument '_' in function definition
```

Ошибка: 2 одинаковых аргумента.
Вот информация по этой ошибке: https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/F831.html
Питону кажется, что "_" - это имя переменной, а не знак удаления.

Мою проблему решает удаление *args `def __eq__ (*_):`, но это костыль, потому что функция примет сколько угодно аргументов. Получается, это ошибка интерпретатора. Куда на нее жаловаться?
Минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
def f (_, _):
    pass
```

Comment: Вы хоть знаете что это _ в Python?

Comment: Если одиночный символ.

Comment: @Mike, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: Это буфер _ если что.

Comment: Тима изучите азы, потом что то делайте. А уж тем более утверждайте об ошибке интерпретатора.

Comment: `def __eq__ (_1, _2): return true`

Comment: @Александр, нет не буфер, и не "знак удаления". Подчеркивание - обычное имя для переменной, в данном случае - имя аргумента.

Comment: Содержимое этого _ измениться после вызова любой функции ( и ещё чего то там) Так что использовать этот знак как переменную просто опасно..

Comment: @Александр, только в интерактивном режиме, и только значение глобальной переменной `_`. Локальную переменную с именем `_` вполне можно использовать, хотя я бы не рекомендовал этого делать.

Comment: Вообще, см. этот вопрос, в ответе на него подробно расписано: [Каково назначение переменной одно подчеркивание «_»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1207226/1365)

Answer (score 4):

Подчеркивание не знак удаления. никакого удаления в питоне нет. _ это обычное имя переменной, которое просто принято использовать для обозначения, что эти данные не нужны. В то же время никто не запрещает использовать ее как обычную переменную. И да, все параметры надо указать. Напишите например 'a' и 'b'

Comment: Вообще он задаёт одинаковые имена параметров для функции, и спрашивает почему не валидный синтаксис.

Comment: Ваш ответ к чему вообще?

Comment: @Александр ТС считает что ошибка в интерпретаторе. А считает он так потому, что считает подчеркивание специальным "символом удаления", которое заменяет собой любой ненужный аргумент или переменную, в любом количестве